# VBA Error occurs when set a range - 1004 Application Defined Error

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm working on my VBA code to set a range based on the last row in my source data and then create a pivot table on that range. However the last line here goes wrong when I run the code with error 1004 (application defined error). I feel all the variables have been defined and should be alright. The messagebox also gives me the right last row number in source data. Could you please help me to fix? thanks.

```
    Dim PvtTbl As pivotTable
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim PvtTblCache As PivotCache
    Dim wsPvtTbl As Worksheet
    Dim pvtFld As PivotField

    Set wsData = Worksheets("Task List Data Export")
    Set wsPvtTbl = Worksheets("Summary")

    wsPvtTbl.Cells.Clear
    wsPvtTbl.Cells.ColumnWidth = 10

    For Each PvtTbl In wsPvtTbl.PivotTables
    If MsgBox("Delete existing PivotTable!", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    PvtTbl.TableRange2.Clear
    End If
    Next PvtTbl

    Dim last As Long

    With Worksheets("Task List Data Export")
        last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    End With
    MsgBox last
    Set rngData = Worksheets("Task List Data Export").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(last, 15))
```

************************Update************************
Hi I applied Dy.Lee's code and this error finally disappeared. However my next line goes wrong again (Error type mismatch)

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngData, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=wsPvtTbl.Range("B25"), TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

Any Ideas? Thanks again

Comment: ************************Update*************************

Comment: Always qualify `Cells`, etc, to specify which sheet it is referring to - that last line is effectively `Set rngData = Worksheets("Task List Data Export").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 15))` and you can't find a range on one worksheet between the cells on a different worksheet.

Comment: @YowE3K Hi Thank you very much for your tips. This is so useful to clear up my confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

the code would be like this

```
With Worksheets("Task List Data Export")
    Set rngData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(last, 15))
End With
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed. However when I go to the next line (updated above) which is used to generate the pivot table, Error(Type mismatch) appears. Do you have any ideas? thanks.

Comment: @AmadeusNing - Please don't change the question after someone has successfully answered it.  If you have a new problem, you should raise a new question.

Comment: @YowE3K hi thank you for you advice. However I can only raise one question within 90 minutes.